# Should I set model.eval for getting the current training loss in Pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

We set model.train() during training, but during my training iterations, I also want to do a forward pass of the training dataset to see what my new loss is. When doing this, should I temporarily set model.eval()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your network has layers which act different during inference (`torch.nn.BatchNormNd` and `torch.nn.DropoutNd` could be an example, for the second case **all neurons will be used but scaled by inverted probability of keeping neurons**, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193633/how-inverting-the-dropout-compensates-the-effect-of-dropout-and-keeps-expected-v) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170758) for example) **and** you want to test how your network performs currently (which is usually called a `validation` step) then it is mandatory to use `module.eval()`.

It is a common (and very good!) practice to always switch to `eval` mode when doing inference-like things no matter if this changes your actual model.

**EDIT:**

You should also use `with torch.no_grad():` block during inference, see [official tutorial code](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html#pytorch-tensors-and-autograd) as gradients are not needed during this phase and it's wasteful to compute them.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. What do you mean by "inference-like"?

Comment: Inference is a stage when you are only after network's output and you don't need gradient calculations via backpropagation (`backward()` call) or you will not optimize parameters. See also my edit for another important thing. Is this explanation clear?